# Nagios mail alert configuration

Tags: nagios

Recently I configured Nagios with postfix. Whenever server/service is down it used to send mail alerts for every 1 hour till that system/service is up. How can I configure nagios so that it has to send mail alert only once for system/service down and again when status changes to up nagios has to notify me.

Answer (score 2):

In your host/host template/service/service template set notification_interval 0

Answer (score 0):

In your host definition, set notification_interval to 0:

```
define host{
  use                     generic-host
  host_name               example
  address                 example.com
  notification_interval   0
}
```